# Redis intermittent "crash" on Laravel Horizon. Redis stops working every few weeks/months

Tags: laravel, redis, laravel-queue, laravel-horizon

I have an issue with Redis that effects running of Laravel Horizon Queue and I am unsure how to debug it at this stage, so am looking for some advice.

**Issue**

Approx. every 3 - 6 weeks my queues stop running. Every time this happens, the first set of exceptions I see are:

```bash
Redis Exception: socket error on read socket
```

```bash
Redis Exception: read error on connection to 127.0.0.1:6379
```

Both of these are caused by Horizon running the command:

```bash
artisan horizon:work redis
```

**Theory**

We push around 50k - 100k jobs through the queue each day and I am guessing that Redis is running out of resources over the 3-6 week period. Maybe general memory, maybe something else?

I am unsure if this is due to a leak wikthin my system or something else.

**Current Fix**

At the moment, I simply run the command `redis-cli FLUSHALL` to completely clear the database and we are back working again for another 3 - 6 weeks. This is obviously not a great fix!

**Other Details**

Currently Redis runs within the webserver (not a dedicated Redis server). I am open to changing that but it is not fixing the root cause of the issue.

**Help!**

At this stage, I am really unsure where to start in terms of debugging and identifing the issue. I feel that is probably a good first step!

Comment: https://linuxhint.com/check-redis-memory-usage/